# How to read delimeted text and store it into SQL table

Tags: c#

I have text which contains three delimiters

```
($ --> Start Point of row ||--> Column Split # --> End Point of row)
```

I would like to know how to read this text and insert it into a SQL table using C# code:

```
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-08:56:44||003100B6#
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-08:56:45||003100B6#
$1004||4001||01||R001||ST||20210507-08:58:36||0088FAE6#
$1004||4001||01||R001||ST||20210507-08:59:31||0088FAE6#
$1001||4001||01||L001||ST||20210507-09:00:21||008984EA#
$1001||4001||01||L001||ST||20210507-09:26:21||008984EA#
$1001||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:26:23||008984EA#
$1002||4001||01||L001||02||20210507-09:28:53||FFFFFFFF#
$1002||4001||01||L001||RS||20210507-09:29:00||FFFFFFFF#
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:29:17||0088704D#
$1002||4001||01||L001||RS||20210507-09:29:36||FFFFFFFF#
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:29:51||0088704D#
$1002||4001||01||L001||AC||20210507-09:29:54||FFFFFFFF#
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:29:57||0088704D#
$1004||4001||01||R001||ST||20210507-09:31:39||0088FAE6#
$1004||4001||01||R001||ST||20210507-09:31:49||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||FF||20210507-09:31:50||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||FH||20210507-09:31:58||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||FF||20210507-09:32:00||008828A3#
$1002||4001||01||L001||ST||20210507-09:35:07||0088704D#
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:35:11||0088704D#
$1002||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:35:12||0088704D#
$1002||4001||01||L001||ST||20210507-09:35:42||008819A4#
$1001||4001||01||L001||ST||20210507-09:35:34||0088821C#
$1001||4001||01||L001||FF||20210507-09:35:36||0088821C#
$1004||4001||01||R001||FF||20210507-09:36:35||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||ST||20210507-09:36:37||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||FF||20210507-09:36:38||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||FF||20210507-09:37:27||008828A3#
$1004||4001||01||R001||ST||20210507-09:37:30||008828A3#
```

Comment: Did you give it a try with the C# code? If yes, please post your code.

Comment: I don;t know how to read this via C# Code

Comment: can you mention the column header?

Comment: you can take col1 to col7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Imports
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

//if you are reading from text file.
string delimitedText = File.ReadAllText("~/delimited.txt");

//Split by carriage-return
foreach (string row in delimitedText.Split('\r'))
{
    //Trim Start And End
    string rowValue = row.TrimStart('$').TrimEnd('#');
    
    foreach (string column in Regex.Split(rowValue, @"\|\|"))
    {
        //Save the columns
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try to read lines using File.ReadAllLines

Comment: Yes.. File.ReadAllLines() does eliminate to split by carriage return.  I was not sure if the OP was reading it from File directly or had the delimited text already as a string.

Comment: This is mostly a remark for OP :) To get him some ideas.